# Problem drawing into an ItemizedOverlay MapView on Satellite mode

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

i subclass the ItemizedOverlay to draw a custom graphics for my items, the problem is that i have the MapView and my custom overlay with a List items... when i construct the items, populate and draw in the "map mode" (setSatellite(false)) works good, but when i change the mode to setSatellite(true) my custom overlay holds all the items but not refresh, invalidate, redraw the map, i try invoking all those methods and nothing. i also try, claring the overlays and adding a new one (pretty bad) and nothing. Anyone knows what happens with the custom overlay when i change set setSatellite true or false?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved this, the problem was on the activity hierarchy, because i have a TabActivity with two childs activity, one in map mode and the other in satellite mode and the list of itemizedoverlays was not shared between the activitys, indeed there are two distinct activitys launched on tab widget selection.